# How to check if JSON object is empty in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I'm reading JSON data with PHP and that data contains empty objects (like `{}`). So the problem is, I have to handle the case when object is empty in different manner but I can't find good enough way to do the check. `empty(get_object_vars(object))` looks too scary and very inefficient. Is there good way to do the check?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9412126/3995261

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How many objects are you unserializing? Unless `empty(get_object_vars($object))` or casting to array proves to be a major slowdown/bottleneck, I wouldn't worry about it – Greg's solution is just fine.

I'd suggest using the the `$associative` flag when decoding the JSON data, though:

```
json_decode($data, true)
```

This decodes JSON objects as plain old PHP arrays instead of as `stdClass` objects. Then you can check for empty objects using `empty()` and create objects of a user-defined class instead of using `stdClass`, which is probably a good idea in the long run.

Comment: But if you find a plain old PHP array, how do you know if it was encoded from [] or {}? They aren't different in PHP, but they are in JSON.

Answer (score 28):

You could cast it to an array (unfortunately you can't do this within a call to `empty()`:

```
$x = (array)$obj;
if (empty($x))
    ...
```

Or cast to an array and `count()`:

```
if (count((array)$obj))
    ...
```

Comment: Isn't it the same as with get_object_vars? I.e. not really efficient? :)

Comment: I haven't tested it but unless you're having performance problems and have identified this as the bottleneck I don't think it's worth worrying yourself over it.

Comment: It's not easy to stop worrying about unnecessary array transformations if you were a C++ programmer most of your life :) It means memory allocation and copying stuff for something that should take just a quick check if a bit is set.

Comment: The count of an array is useless to distinguish [] from {} in JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Try without using `empty()` which is:

```
get_object_vars($obj) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

On [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) we can read the note:

> When using `empty()` on inaccessible object properties, the `__isset()` overloading method will be called, if declared.

Which means when using `empty()` on an object which is having `__get()` method, it will always return True.

Answer (score 0):

I had to tell if an object was empty or not, but I also had to ignore private and protected properties, so I made this little function with which you can do this.

```
function empty_obj(&$object, $ignore_private = true, $ignore_protected = true) {
  $obj_name = get_class($object);
  $obj = (array)$object;

  foreach(array_keys($obj) as $prop) {
    $is_private = $is_protected = false;

    $prop = preg_replace("/[^\w*]/", '', $prop);
    $prop_name = str_replace(array($obj_name, '*'), '', $prop);

    if(preg_match("~^$obj_name$prop_name$~", $prop))
      $is_private = true;
    if(preg_match("~^\*$prop_name$~", $prop))
      $is_protected = true;

    if(!$is_private || !$is_protected || ($is_private && !$ignore_private) || ($is_protected && !$ignore_protected))
      return;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is more or less effective than casting to an array but I would guess more.  You could just start to loop the object and as soon as you find something you have an answer and stop looping.

```
function is_obj_empty($obj){
   if( is_null($obj) ){
      return true;
   }
   foreach( $obj as $key => $val ){
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```