# How to check that an object is empty in PHP?

Tags: php, object

How to find if an object is empty or not in PHP.

Following is the code in which `$obj` is holding XML data. How can I check if it's empty or not?

My code:

```
$obj = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP object holding XML data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411681/php-object-holding-xml-data)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if object is empty in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389431/how-to-check-if-object-is-empty-in-php)

Answer (score 152):

You can cast to an array and then check if it is empty or not

```
$arr = (array)$obj;
if (!$arr) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The typecasting doesn't work for me, because I get the error:
    **PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(array)' (array) (T_ARRAY_CAST) in ...**

I use PHP version 5.4.28 and the first option with two lines of code works for me.

Comment: Had the same error when uploading a WordPress plugin, seems that they also use an older version of PHP.

Comment: empty doesn't actually check if an array is empty, `empty($var)` equivalent to `(!isset($var) || !$var)`. You can replace your `empty($arr)`s with `!$arr` since `array() == FALSE`

Comment: The reason `empty((array) $obj)` does not work in PHP 5.4+ has nothing to do with typecasting on one line. You get the error because `empty()` takes a reference to the variables passed to it, and it cannot get a reference when typecasting unless you first store that typecasted variable in another variable. It does this because of what I described in my previous comment. It's rather frustrating that this is the accepted answer since it can lead people to believe that `empty()` checks if an array is "empty" which is not true - that's just a side effect of what it actually does.

Comment: Will it work in php 7+, Or is it the right way to fix it.

Answer (score 40):

**Edit**: I didn't realize they wanted to specifically check if a SimpleXMLElement object is empty. I left the old answer below

### **Updated Answer (SimpleXMLElement)**:

For SimpleXMLElement:

If by empty you mean has no properties:

```
$obj = simplexml_load_file($url);
if ( !$obj->count() )
{
    // no properties
}
```

OR

```
$obj = simplexml_load_file($url);
if ( !(array)$obj )
{
    // empty array
}
```

If SimpleXMLElement is one level deep, and by empty you actually mean that it only has properties [PHP considers falsey](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (or no properties):

```
$obj = simplexml_load_file($url);
if ( !array_filter((array)$obj) )
{
    // all properties falsey or no properties at all
}
```

If SimpleXMLElement is more than one level deep, you can start by converting it to a pure array:

```
$obj = simplexml_load_file($url);
// `json_decode(json_encode($obj), TRUE)` can be slow because
// you're converting to and from a JSON string.
// I don't know another simple way to do a deep conversion from object to array
$array = json_decode(json_encode($obj), TRUE);
if ( !array_filter($array) )
{
    // empty or all properties falsey
}
```

---

### **Old Answer (simple object)**:

If you want to check if a simple object (type `stdClass`) is completely empty (no keys/values), you can do the following:

```
// $obj is type stdClass and we want to check if it's empty
if ( $obj == new stdClass() )
{
    echo "Object is empty"; // JSON: {}
}
else
{
    echo "Object has properties";
}
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

**Edit**: added example

```
$one = new stdClass();
$two = (object)array();

var_dump($one == new stdClass()); // TRUE
var_dump($two == new stdClass()); // TRUE
var_dump($one == $two); // TRUE

$two->test = TRUE;
var_dump($two == new stdClass()); // FALSE
var_dump($one == $two); // FALSE

$two->test = FALSE;
var_dump($one == $two); // FALSE

$two->test = NULL;
var_dump($one == $two); // FALSE

$two->test = TRUE;
$one->test = TRUE;
var_dump($one == $two); // TRUE

unset($one->test, $two->test);
var_dump($one == $two); // TRUE
```

Comment: Doesn't work in PHP7.2: ``PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::count()``

Comment: @juha-untinen The solution with `->count()` is specifically for instances of `SimpleXMLElement` and not for instances of `stdClass`. I believe all of this still works in PHP7.2.

Answer (score 28):

You can cast your object into an array, and test its count like so:

```
if(count((array)$obj)) {
   // doStuff
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Imagine if the object is not empty and in a way quite big, why would you waste the resources to cast it to array or serialize it...

This is a very easy solution I use in JavaScript. Unlike the mentioned solution that casts an object to array and check if it is empty, or to encode it into JSON, this simple function is very efficient concerning used resources to perform a simple task.

```
function emptyObj( $obj ) {
    foreach ( $obj AS $prop ) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The solution works in a very simple manner: It wont enter a foreach loop at all if the object is empty and it will return `true`. If it's not empty it will enter the `foreach` loop and return `false` right away, not passing through the whole set.

Answer (score 11):

Using `empty()` won't work as usual when using it on an object, because the `__isset()` overloading method will be called instead, if declared.

Therefore you can use `count()` (if the object is [Countable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php)).

Or by using `get_object_vars()`, e.g.

```
get_object_vars($obj) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

Answer (score 7):

Another possible solution which doesn't need casting to `array`:

```
// test setup
class X { private $p = 1; } // private fields only => empty
$obj = new X;
// $obj->x = 1;


// test wrapped into a function
function object_empty( $obj ){
  foreach( $obj as $x ) return false;
  return true;
}


// inline test
$object_empty = true;
foreach( $obj as $object_empty ){ // value ignored ... 
  $object_empty = false; // ... because we set it false
  break;
}


// test    
var_dump( $object_empty, object_empty( $obj ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

there's no unique safe way to check if an object is empty

php's count() first casts to array, but casting can produce an empty array, depends by how the object is implemented (extensions' objects are often affected by those issues)

in your case you have to use $obj->count();

http://it.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php

(that is not php's count http://www.php.net/count )

Answer (score 2):

**in PHP version 8**

consider you want to access a property of an object, but you are not sure that the object itself is null or not and it could cause error. in this case you can use `Nullsafe operator` that introduced in php `8` as follow:

> ```
> $country = $session?->user?->getAddress()?->country;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you cast anything in PHP as a (bool), it will tell you right away if the item is an object, primitive type or null. Use the following code:

```
$obj = simplexml_load_file($url);

if (!(bool)$obj) {
    print "This variable is null, 0 or empty";
} else {
    print "Variable is an object or a primitive type!";
}
```

Comment: wrong. $x = new \stdClass(); var_dump((bool)$x); prints 'true';
In your case, simpleXml may return false in some cases

Comment: Correct. new stdClass() is a valid object, that's why it's true. PHP manual says, simplexml_load_file(), "Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the XML document, or FALSE on failure." So, if you cast (bool)simplexml_load_file(), it will be true (because the function returned an object) but false (because the function returned false).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866062/12308478) from kenorb, here's another one-liner for objects with *public* vars:

```php
if (!empty(get_object_vars($myObj))) { ... }
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @mickmackusa's comment below - below is a more succinct one-liner, since this converts the object to an associative array (of accessible properties), and an empty array is falsy in PHP.

```php
if (get_object_vars($myObj)) { ... }
```

**Edit 2:** In the event that your object is not a true object, `get_object_vars()` may produce warnings or alerts. This checks that the var is an object before ensuring that it's populated:

```php
if (is_object($myObj) && get_object_vars($myObj)) { ... }
```

Just to reiterate - this is for objects with public/accessible variables. Objects with static, private, or protected vars will render false, which may be unexpected. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: `!empty()` is also checking the existence of the passed in argument -- which is unnecessary.  The simper way of doing the same thing is `if (get_object_vars($myObj)) {`

Answer (score 0):

If an object is "empty" or not is a matter of definition, and because it depends on the nature of the object the class represents, it is for the class to define.

PHP itself regards every instance of a class as not empty.

```
class Test { }
$t = new Test();
var_dump(empty($t));

// results in bool(false)
```

There cannot be a generic definition for an "empty" object. You might argue in the above example the result of `empty()` should be `true`, because the object does not represent any content. But how is PHP to know? Some objects are never meant to represent content (think factories for instance), others always represent a meaningful value (think `new DateTime()`).

In short, you will have to come up with your own criteria for a specific object, and test them accordingly, either from outside the object or from a self-written `isEmpty()` method in the object.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a json_decode of a string in post request. None of the above worked for me, in the end I used this:

```
$post_vals = json_decode($_POST['stuff']);

if(json_encode($post_vals->object) != '{}')
{
    // its not empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if object type is null or not.

```
if( $obj !== null )
{
     // DO YOUR WORK
}
```

Comment: You can't simply check for `null`, `$obj = new \stdClass()` is empty, but not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

count($the_object) > 0  this is working and can be use for array too

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array_filter($array);
if(!empty($array)) {
    echo "not empty";
}
```

or

```
if(count($array) > 0) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    echo 'No Error';
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).