# How to check if stdClass object is empty or not in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Check if an Object is empty in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412126/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-empty-in-php)

I have this empty object

```
Array (
    [cart_items] => stdClass Object
        (
        )
)
```

When I use `empty()/is_null()` , it doesn't work. When I use `sizeof($object)`, it returns one.

How can I check it?

Comment: check this `empty($object['cart_items'])`

Comment: I'm getting this error Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Zend_Session_Namespace as array and when i use it like this empty($object->cart_items), then also it doesn'w work.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Cast to an array first

```
$tmp = (array) $object;
var_dump(empty($tmp));
```

The reason is, that an object is an object and there is no useful definition of "an empty object", because there are enough classes out there, that only contains methods, but no properties. Should they considered as "empty"?

Comment: if($object == new \stdClass())
{
 // empty
}
else
{
// not empty
}

Answer (score 20):

Check if `count( (array)$yourObject) ) == 0`.

But I'd better define my own class, and provide it with a meaningful `isEmpty()` method.

Comment: But stdClass is for use when you dont want to build your own class :)