# Why doesn't empty() work on a stdClass

Tags: php

I'm facing this dilemma, basically I want to create an error object if a certain task isn't met. Now to understand what I've got to send back to the user, I need to check to see if that error object is either empty or has data. The issue is this:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
var_dump(empty($obj)); // returns false
```

<sup>*As you can see in this* [***`example`***](http://tehplayground.com/#ewJFHgYXu)*, it's returning `false` instead of `true` as it's empty.*</sup>

```
$o = new stdClass();
$a = array();

var_dump(empty($o));
var_dump(empty($a));
```

<sup>[***`Example`***](http://$o%20=%20new%20stdClass();%20$a%20=%20array();%20%20var_dump(empty($o));%20var_dump(empty($a));)</sup>

This works perfectly fine for an array, but does anyone know why this is happening for objects?

---

I've read [answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14137178/2518525) which state to cast it as an array, but my question is this:

> Why does it return false when it's empty? What is the logic behind it?
>   If I wanted an array, I would've started with that.

Comment: [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues) Also see: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: If you really need to check if an object is empty, just cast it to an array: `if (empty((array)$stdClass))`

Comment: You are creating an object and assigning it to $obj that means $obj is not empty.

Comment: @Rizier123 Perfect, that's what I was looking for! if you chuck it up as an answer I'll accept

Comment: Then Empty function will check it is empty OR not. If its empty return TRUE else FALSE

Comment: If I were you and if I coded what you did, I'd have my object implement method `isEmpty()` which would check properties that contain errors. Then I can just use OO approach, if I'm using objects already, and I can do `if($myObject->isEmpty())` or even better `if($myObject->hasErrors())`. I don't see why would anyone use procedural approach at all. Avoiding setting mines removes all possibility of setting one off.

Comment: @Darren - we often miss the forest because of the damn trees, but coffee should help with that. Anyway, glad I could help a bit :>

Comment: @N.B. That would be my accepted answer if you want to post it! You get 1000 cookies for pointing out my idiocy! :P

Comment: It's all good, the question was about `empty` construct and objects so the provided answer is answering that, for any future googlers that stumble upon here so it's all good if you ask me. I'm ok with helping you, no need for any imaginary points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From php.net:

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

Every object you create won't be "empty".