# Check if object/array is empty

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if the following is empty or not.

```
{"players":""}
```

I have a function that gets that from an api/site and.. well, heres the code.

```
function getPlayers($server) {
    // Fetches content from url and json_decodes it
    $playersList = getUrl('http://api.iamphoenix.me/list/?server_ip=' . $server);
    // Attempting to check if it's empty.
    if ($playersList != "") {
        // convert list of comma-separated names into array
        $players = explode(',', $playersList->players);
        foreach ($players as $player) {
            echo '<img title="'.$player.'" src="https://minotar.net/avatar/'.$player.'/32">';
        }
    } else {
        return 'empty';
    }
}
```

However, using `!=`, `empty()`, or `isset()`, I still get an empty string, example:

```
https://minotar.net/avatar//32
```

Where it should be..

```
https://minotar.net/avatar/Notch/32
```

When it's empty, I'd like it to just return 'empty'.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `if (!empty($player)) {` within the `foreach`?

Comment: I think the function getUrl returns an object of data not array of data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check that an object is empty in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412126/how-to-check-that-an-object-is-empty-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were able to have some output, see my changes in the codes.

```
function getPlayers($server) {
    // Fetches content from url and json_decodes it
    $playersList = getUrl('http://api.iamphoenix.me/list/?server_ip=' . $server);
    // Attempting to check if it's empty.
    if ($playersList != "") {
        // convert list of comma-separated names into array
        $players = explode(',', $playersList->players);
        // check conversion
        if(is_array($players) && !empty($players){
            foreach ($players as $player) {
                echo '<img title="'.$player.'" src="https://minotar.net/avatar/'.$player.'/32">';
            }
        } else {
            return 'empty';
        }
    } else {
        return 'empty';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure php you can check the url segments like

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);

if($segments[2] == '') { 
}
//or
if(empty($segments[2])) { 
}

//or do your condition
```

if you are using codeigniter you might say

```
if(empty($this->uri->segment(2)))
```

But be sure you loaded the `url helper`

Hope I understand your question!

Answer (score 0):

try this

if (isset($playersList) && is_array($playersList) && !empty($playersList)) {

```
    // convert list of comma-separated names into array
    $players = explode(',', $playersList->players);
    foreach ($players as $player) {
        echo '<img title="'.$player.'" src="https://minotar.net/avatar/'.$player.'/32">';
    }
} else {
    return 'empty';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this;

```
print_r($playersList);
```

just after you set it to see what it actually is. My guess is that you are not getting what you suspect from the `getURL` call.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more equals sign to take type comparison into account as well

```
if ($playerList !== '')
```