# How to check empty object array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I got below set of empty object array and when I am using php `empty` function, below object array bypass the `empty` function.

```
stdClass Object
(
)
```

Please suggest me, how can I identify the blank object array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check that an object is empty in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412126/how-to-check-that-an-object-is-empty-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the object to associative array using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($obj), TRUE);
if (empty($arr)) {
  // Object is empty.
}
```

`json_decode` function returns associative array if second parameter is set `TRUE` (even if object is passed).

**Working example:**

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($obj), TRUE);
if (empty($arr)) {
  echo 'empty';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to array and check :

```
$array = (array) $object;

if (empty($array))
```

or

```
count($array)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by

```
$array = array_filter($array);
if(!empty($array)) {
    echo "not empty";
}
```