# test object is null in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, null

I want to test if an object is null or not, I have the follwing code

```
$listcontact = array();
$contact=$ms->search('email','test@live.Fr');
var_dump(($contact));
```

and the result if `$listcontact` not null is give as follow

```
object(stdClass)[6]
public 'item' => string 'dfdfsd' (length=7)
```

in the case it's null , I get the following result

```
object(stdClass)[6]
```

How I can test the variable `$listcontact` exists or not? I've tried with `is_null` and `(empty()` but not work

Comment: You can use `count` method of php [Documentation Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: How is *$listcontact* involved in setting *$contact*? Your code does not show any connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a PHP array is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216052/how-to-tell-if-a-php-array-is-empty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function `is_null()` as follows :

```
is_null($listcontact);
```

The **Return Value** is :

> Returns TRUE if var is null, FALSE otherwise.

### EDIT

Also you can use this :

```
  if ( !$YOUR_OBJECT->count() ){
        //null
  }
```

For more information see those [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412126/how-to-check-that-an-object-is-empty-in-php)

Try using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php)

```
$EmptyArray= array_filter($listcontact);

if (!empty($EmptyArray)){

}
else{
    //nothing there
}
```

Comment: I test it but not worked, beceause I use webservice in php and the called function return a String[] variable

Comment: Try to check if your count(YOUROBJECT) == 0 it's empty

Comment: Did it work @MajdiTaleb? If it did feel free to mark this quesiton as a correct (The green check) :P

Answer (score 6):

You can use a built-in function [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) to check null values. So, use:

```
if (is_null($listcontact))
  // Yes, it is null.
else
  // Do something.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get `object stdclass` with var_dump, it must not be null.

The fastest way to check if a variable is null is to use `$listcontact === null`.

> in the case it's null , I get the following result
>
> object(stdClass)[6]

This means that the `search()` function didn't return null.

Answer (score 0):

I found a correct answer for this

```
 $tmp = (array) $listcontact;
 var_dump(empty($tmp));
if(empty($tmp)){
echo "empty"
}
```

Comment: You can also use `is_null()`. Does `is_null` work for you?

Comment: I test it but not worked, beceause I use webservice in php and the called function return a String[] variable