# Parsing Plain Mails

Tags: php, email, object

While trying to read plain mails with imap_fetchbody I want to receive the used charset which can be found in the fetched array grabbed by imap_fetchstructure which can look like :

```
stdClass Object
(
[type] => 0
[encoding] => 4
[ifsubtype] => 1
[subtype] => PLAIN
[ifdescription] => 0
[ifid] => 0
[lines] => 13
[bytes] => 285
[ifdisposition] => 0
[ifdparameters] => 0
[ifparameters] => 1
[parameters] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [attribute] => CHARSET
                [value] => iso-8859-1
            )

    )

)
```

The key [parameters] holds the desired value. Unfortunately it can look also like

```
[parameters] => stdClass Object
    (
    )
```

How could I avoid running into a fatal error when asking for

```
$charsetType = $structure->parameters;
```

I would need to identify that this time [parameters] is empty and does not hold a value.

Any idea how I could check in this case that this object is empty?
I bet it is something simple but I seem to be too tired to grab it...I tried empty() and isset() but both doesnt work as the key is there and not empty (somehow).

Comment: What *does* it contain? `var_dump` it.

Comment: Hi, a var_dump($structure->parameters) gives exactly this: stdClass Object ( ). So there is something in this array - but I am not sure how I can detect this as something with nothing ...

Comment: OK, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412126/how-to-check-that-an-object-is-empty-in-php then.

Comment: I knew it was something not-rocket-science :) Thanks for the hint - very helpful!

Comment: Uhm.. how could I close this questions as it has been answered now?

Comment: I've closed it already by marking it as a duplicate.